# Duplicate a record while updating values from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am migrating some data in a wordpress database, and getting stuck on the last part.

I have three tables, one is an official WordPress table and two are temporary tables. Here is their structure:

> wp_term_relationships: object_id, term_taxonomy_id, term_order
>
> old_terms: term_id, slug
>
> new_terms: term_id, slug

The slug matches between the old_terms and new_terms tables. I need to go through wp_term_relationships and create a new record using the following rules:

1. Anytime the term_taxonomy_id (wp_term_relationships) matches the term_id (old_terms)
2. Create a new record Where

   - `object_id = wp_term_relationships.object_id`
   - `term_taxonomy_id = new_terms.term_id WHERE new_terms.slug = old_terms.slug`
   - `term_order = wp_term_relationships.term_order`

I have tried dozens of different sql calls, but cannot seem to figure this one out. This was the last one I Tried

```
INSERT INTO wp_term_relationships ( object_id, term_taxonomy_id, term_order )
SELECT object_id, new_terms.term_id, term_order
WHERE term_id = old_terms.term_id ON new_terms.slug = old_terms.slug
```

I've been at this for awhile, and haven't made any progress. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, after struggling through this, I finally was able to make it work with the following code.

```
INSERT INTO wp_term_relationships ( object_id, term_taxonomy_id, term_order )
SELECT c.object_id, a.tax_term_id, c.term_order
FROM new_terms AS a
LEFT JOIN old_terms AS b ON a.slug = b.slug
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships AS c ON b.term_id = c.term_taxonomy_id
WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN ( SELECT term_id FROM old_terms )
```

If anyone runs into something similar, feel free to reach out. I feel like I have a much better handle on the mechanics of what is happening now than I used to.